# What is the use of Hibernate first level cache if each transaction uses a separate session.?

Tags: hibernate

I use hibernate in my application. I use individual session object for each transaction. Then how is session cache useful? Do i have to use other levels of caches.?

Comment: Rightly  the first level cache is a session level cache, it is enabled by default and you cant disable it. It is associated with your session and when you're talking about first level cache you're talking actually of session it is the same.

Comment: Second level cache is a cache shared by all sessions in your app it can be usefull if you have for example reference data common at all your application (coutry list, departement, etc ...) it is very efficient for readonly data. This cache is disable by default , up to you to enable it or not.

Answer (score 0):

All your persist, update, delete operations that you invoke within your session will be stored in that cache. 
The DB will be hit AFTER you flush persistence context, so that is the moment when the contents of that cache is transferred to DB. So, it can still improve your performance, even if it is limited to single session only.

There is a chance that when you try to find an entity and it is already in the cache, the DB won't be hit by that find - another possible performance gain.

There are so-called second level caches, not limited to single persistence context, you can read about them, but that is a more complex topic. ;)